# Embedded binary is not signed with the same certificate

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, provisioning-profile

I was compiling my app without any problem on my device and without any reason I started getting this error

> error: Embedded binary is not signed with the same certificate as the
>   parent app. Verify the embedded binary target's code sign settings
>   match the parent app's.
>
> ```
>   Embedded Binary Signing Certificate:    - (Ad Hoc Code Signed)          
>   Parent App Signing Certificate:     iPhone Developer: F ***(*****)
> ```

On Target > Built Setting > Code Signing I have set everywhere the same iOS developer but  still have the same problem. I also deleted the user account, deleted the certificate from the Keychain and regenerate them with the fix issue button but without any success.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that when you say embedded binary its a dynamic embedded framework.

Is your embedded binary a subproject?

If so check that it is signed with the same certificate as you are signing the host project (or don't sign at all). The host app can sign the embedded frameworks when copying to its framework directory.

If you are adding the embedded framework already compiled, you can delete the _codesign directory from the framework's directory and have your host app sign the framework when copying it into the frameworks directory of the app.

(There is a small check box you can toggle)

Comment: I get the error from the WatchKit Extension.appex. I disabled code signing for the WatchKit but I get an error telling me that the watchKit App has to be signed. I also can't find the checkbox for signing frameworks when copying them

Comment: Try creating a skeleton project with the same setup you currently have (app + watch etc). Then copy the same settings to your problematic app.